# Handling status bar height depending on orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, layout

I've found that with album orientation on iPhones status bar disappears. My views were adjusted just below status bar using `.frame` property. Now, when status bar disappears, I want to move them higher. What's correct way to do that? Also on iPads status bar doesn't disappear so I would like some kind of universal way to handle that.

Currently I can overload `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:` in my controller and adjust settings there. But I can't found whether status bar will be hidden after transition or not.

I use `.xib` files, not storyboards, if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same issue.I overcome this by following

```
 Best to use
    -(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    {
      //........
    }
```

method in your coding.It automatically lays out the view.It adjusts the size according 
the view orientation.I applied this method for iPhone and iPad.It works perfectly.

Before that you should follow the below things

1.plist

```
View controller-based status bar appearance   boolean   NO
```

in appDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden=NO;
    [application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
    [application setStatusBarHidden:NO];
}
```

In your ViewController

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    //For iPAD I set the bounds because it calls this method,Once it returns from previous view controller or background to foreground
    self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0, -20, 1024, 768);
}

-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    self.view.clipsToBounds = YES;
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenHeight = 0.0;
    screenHeight = screenRect.size.width;
    CGRect screenFrame = CGRectMake(0, 20, self.view.frame.size.width,screenHeight-20);
    CGRect viewFrame1 = [self.view convertRect:self.view.frame toView:nil];
    if (!CGRectEqualToRect(screenFrame, viewFrame1))
    {
        self.view.frame = screenFrame;
        self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
        NSLog(@"width is - %f",[[self view] bounds].size.width);
        NSLog(@"height is - %f",[[self view] bounds].size.height);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I implemented `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and used `[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height` to calculate status bar height. It worked just fine.

Comment: Welcome vbezhenar.Now I am happy since  my code works fine and helpful for you brother.